# Как правильно написать запрос sql на добавление записи в таблицу БД? c# VS13

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, visual-studio-2013, textbox

Мне нужно сохранить данные из textBox'ов в новою строку таблицы "Writers" моей БД.
Я пытался сделать это так, но видимо где то накосячил, ошибок нет но таблица не изменяется!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше вставлять код текстом, а не снимком эрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создали команду, но не выполнили её. Судя по коду вам нужно добавить

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Появилась ошибка, добавил скрин. Как исправить?

Comment: @Vyacheslav в тексте ошибки же всё написано. Или нам построчно Ваш код отлаживать?